# Updating image Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

From an API I am getting a URL for image. The image url is stored in sqflite and I am using that image url to display image everywhere in the app using NetworkImage. Now in one screen I have one dialog to update image where I am using ImagePicker to pick Image and then upload image to server. In return of upload image API I am getting the updated imageurl. So after getting this updated url I am updating the imagurl in sqflite. But the issue now is even if the url is updated in sqflite the app is displaying old image. When I debug I found out that I am getting the updated image url itself but displaying old image only. I even tried using Provider for this but still same. Can anyone help resolving this?

Note: Image updates only if app is closed and reopend

Comment: can you please show your code !!!

Comment: @AR Image updates only if app is closed and reopend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using a `CircleAvatar` instead of `NetworkImage`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but It might be flutter bug

1.uninstall app

2.try this command `flutter clean`

3.and re-install your app

i hope it helps..